# Installing openssh on centos

Tags: hadoop, ssh, centos, mapr

I am trying to install sshpass on centos, as I want to install MapR on our systems.

I am following guidelines given here: 
http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Quick+Installation+Guide

I get following issue:

```
sudo yum install sshpass
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.excellmedia.net
 * extras: centos.excellmedia.net
 * updates: centos.excellmedia.net
Setting up Install Process
No package sshpass available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

If somebody can help me to understand where to get sshpass from it will be great.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BTW sshpass is available in epel repos by that name itself. You should probably add the epel repo to your yum configuration.

```
[root@rh-1 ~]# yum whatprovides */sshpass
Loaded plugins: product-id, security, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
centos                                                                                                                                                   | 3.7 kB     00:00     
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                            | 8.4 kB     00:00     
epel                                                                                                                                                     | 4.4 kB     00:00     
epel/primary_db                                                                                                                                          | 6.3 MB     00:03     
maprecosystem                                                                                                                                            |  951 B     00:00     
maprecosystem/primary                                                                                                                                    |  12 kB     00:00     
maprecosystem                                                                                                                                                             74/74
maprtech                                                                                                                                                 |  951 B     00:00     
centos/filelists_db                                                                                                                                      | 5.9 MB     00:15     
epel/filelists_db                                                                                                                                        | 9.0 MB     00:07     
maprecosystem/filelists                                                                                                                                  | 333 kB     00:00     
maprtech/filelists                                                                                                                                       |  16 kB     00:00     
sshpass-1.05-1.el6.x86_64 : Non-interactive SSH authentication utility
Repo        : epel
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/bin/sshpass
```

Answer (score 0):

The package that contains the openssh server on CentOS as far as I know is not called `sshpass` but `openssh-server` so run

```
 yum install openssh-server
```

Comment: Yep. Thank. 
But how to use it ? Openssh-server

Answer (score 0):

The better way would be to setup the ssh keys for passwordless login. Setup the private and public keys and copy them over to the other nodes. See this tutorial [SSH Passwordless Login Using SSH Keygen in 5 Easy Steps](http://www.tecmint.com/ssh-passwordless-login-using-ssh-keygen-in-5-easy-steps/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't find sshpass package in default Centos repositories. You must be installed epel-release repository then install sshpass package.
For installing epel-release on your centos run below command.

```
yum install epel-release
```